# Excel 2016: FLOOR.MATH function error combined with MAX

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem with the floor.math function in Excel 2016.

I'm working on some simulation sheets, and need to find the deviance from the target and the "number of steps" used.

The number of steps is defined to be 1 step at 1% deviance and 2 at 2% and so on.

I have the following setup (in Excel):

```
Target:       95%    
Current:      Some%
Deviance:     =MAX(Current-Target;0)
Step:         1%
Step used:    =FLOOR.MATH(Deviance/Step)
```

The current percentage is supposed to be changeable whereas the others are fixed.

An example that works:

```
Target: 95%    
Current: 92.5%
Deviance: 2.5%
Step: 1%
Step used: 2
```

An example that doesn't work:

```
Target: 95%    
Current: 93%
Deviance: 2%
Step: 1%
Step used: 1 ???
```

So as you can see I'm having some troubles with the way Excel treats the floor of an integer, when the number originates from the MAX function. It works when I tried it with an integer I manually put in.

Please note, that I have tried the regular floor function as well.

Can anybody explain why this problem originates and/or a way to fix this or overcome it.

Thank you.

Comment: Floating point calculations aren’t accurate. 2% is 0.02 and cant be expressed accurately. Calculate further and you’ll probably get a number very close to 2 but not quite so floor makes it 1. You can add a very small bias to the calculation to push it over.

Comment: But I have tried typing manually 0.02/0.01 and then using the floor.math function and it works??

Comment: And what about the whole path? (0.95-0.93)/0.01?

Comment: Ah yeah, alright now it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Sami says. You can avoid this by rounding you deviance. For instance:

```
=FLOOR.MATH(ROUND(deviance,10)/steps)
```